# Different calculation on different calculator vs. one I scripted

Tags: javascript, css, class, settimeout, addition

On clicking div `click`, div `three` background color should change and then change back after a second. I have the code below which adds the class but the style doesn't show on the page.

```js
let temp = document.querySelector('.three');
document.querySelector('.clickhere').addEventListener('click', () => {
  temp.classList.add('.select');
  console.log(temp);
  setTimeout(function() {
    temp.classList.remove('.select');
    console.log(temp);
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.one {
  background-color: red;
}

.two {
  background-color: green;
}

.three {
  background-color: blue;
}

.select {
  background-color: black;
}

.clickhere {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  ONE
</div>
<div class="two">
  TWO
</div>
<div class="three">
  THREE
</div>
<div class="clickhere">
  CLICK HERE
</div>
```

Comment: Change `.select` to `select` in your JavaScript.

Comment: @maazadeeb Thanks. But why did it work? Aren't classnames to have a '.' in front?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated your snippet, I only had to replace `.select` with `select`

It's important to use period before the css classes only when selecting them with jQuery, when adding a new class and removing it, you should just write the name of it like you would inside the `div` tag.

EDIT: I just saw that the question was already answered in the comments, credits to @maazadeeb! :)

```js
let temp = document.querySelector('.three');
document.querySelector('.clickhere').addEventListener('click', () => {
  temp.classList.add('select');
  console.log(temp);
  setTimeout(function() {
    temp.classList.remove('select');
    console.log(temp);
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.one {
  background-color: red;
}

.two {
  background-color: green;
}

.three {
  background-color: blue;
}

.select {
  background-color: black !important;
}

.clickhere {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  ONE
</div>
<div class="two">
  TWO
</div>
<div class="three">
  THREE
</div>
<div class="clickhere">
  CLICK HERE
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

temp.classList.add('**.select**'); should be update as temp.classList.add('**select**');

```js
let temp = document.querySelector('.three');
document.querySelector('.clickhere').addEventListener('click', () => {
    temp.classList.add('select');
    setTimeout(function () {
        temp.classList.remove('select');
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.one {
  background-color: red;
}

.two {
  background-color: green;
}

.three {
  background-color: blue;
}

.select {
  background-color: black;
}

.clickhere {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.select {
  background: coral;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
    ONE
</div>
<div class="two">
    TWO
</div>
<div class="three">
    THREE
</div>
<div class="clickhere">
    CLICK HERE
</div>
```